Confidence interval with shortest length for location parameter of uniform distribution $U (\theta, \theta+1)$ based on pivot $X_{(1)} - \theta$
$X_i$ is iid from a uniform distribution on $(\theta, \theta + 1)$, $\theta \in R$. Show that $X_{(1)} − \theta$ is a pivot.
Showing that the pivot pdf does not depend on theta, i solved by first finding the CDF of $X_{(1)}$. That is
$$F_{X_{(1)}} = 1 - \prod_1^n(1-F_{X_{(i)}})$$
$$= 1-(1-(x-\theta))^n \text{ for } \theta < x < \theta + 1$$
Now if I let $Y = X_{(1)} − \theta$ and find the cdf of Y, I will have
$$ F_Y(y) = 1-(1-y)^n \text{ for } 0< y < 1$$
Finding the pdf of y is given as
$$f_Y(y) = n(1-y)^{n-1}$$
Since the pdf does not depend on $\theta$, hence $X_{(1)} − \theta$ is a pivot.
I am not sure if what I have solved is correct, Can someone help me explain if it is not correct.
Also, how do I find the shortest length $(1-\alpha)$ level confidence interval for $\theta$ based on this pivot?

it looks correct to me. (Some checks you can do: is the PDF normalized? Does the plot look intuitively like you'd expect?)

Note, you don't need to find the PDF just to show it's a pivot... you're already done once it drops out of the CDF. What's going on here is that $X-\theta$ is $U(0,1)$, i.e. $\theta$ is a just a translation parameter, so anything you can compute just from the quantities $X_i-\theta$ will be a pivot.

Now, how do I find the shortest length? Can I use quantiles to find the shortest length of the pivot using the cdf?

Yes, you want a CI of the form $[X_{(1)}-t, X_{(i)}]$ and so need to compute $P(X_{(1)}-t\le \theta)$.

As you have also shown,
$$X_{(1)}-\theta \sim \text{Beta}(1,n),$$
which shows $X_{(1)}-\theta$ is a pivot for $\theta$.
Any confidence interval for the random variable $W$ with $\text{Beta}(1,n)$ distribution can be given by $(l_\beta, u_\beta)$ with
$$l_\beta=1-\left (1-(1-\beta)\alpha \right)^{\frac 1 n}$$
$$u_\beta=1-(\beta\alpha)^{\frac 1 n}$$
for some  $\beta \in [0,1]$ , that is,
$$\mathbb P \left (l_\beta\le W \le u_\beta \right )=1-\alpha.$$

Note that for $w\in(0,1)$, $ F_W(w) = 1-(1-w)^n$, and as shown in the above figure:
$$ F_W(u_\beta) = 1-\beta\alpha \\ F_W(l_\beta) = (1-\beta)\alpha.$$
Thus, any interval estimator obtained based on the pivot $X_{(1)}-\theta$ is of the form:
$$\left (X_{(1)}-u_\beta, X_{(1)}-l_\beta \right)$$
for some  $\beta \in [0,1]$. The length of the above interval is constant and given by
$$L(\beta)=u_\beta -l_\beta, $$
which is minimized for $\beta=1$ since $$\frac{\text{d}L(\beta)}{\text{d}\beta}<0, \, \beta \in [0,1].$$ Hence, the best interval estimator is
$$\left (X_{(1)}-\left (1-\alpha^{\frac 1 n}\right ), X_{(1)} \right).$$

For the upper bound, is it supposed to be $\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ or $(1-\alpha)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

@MaaleFaustus When the confidence level is $1-\alpha$, then $u_1=1-\alpha^{\frac 1 n}$ is correct, obtained from $1-(1-u_1)^n=1-\alpha.$ I just added more details on how $l_\beta$ and $u_\beta$ are obtained.

I have it now. Thank you!
